# Export Function in Display Tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am working on one migration project(Struts --> Spring MVC) but without changing the UI parts. The place where I stuck is my table using Display Tag. I am using Display tag to show data in tabular format like below.

```
<display:table style="width:100%" name="sessionScope.list" id="listID" export="true" sort="list" pagesize="20" defaultorder="ascending">
    <display:column property="rowNumber" title="#"/>
    <display:column property="issuerName" title="Issuer Name" sortable="true" paramId="in" paramProperty="issuerName" />
    <display:column property="contractNumber" title="Contract Number" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="ip" title="IP" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="maturityDate" title="Maturity Date" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

As we know marking `export="true"` gives us "Export options" with options like CSV, Excel, XML.

My problem is, the link that is generated on each options is like below

```
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/WEB-INF/pages/myjsp.jsp?d-445967-e=1&6578706f7274=1
```

As you can notice, its like jsps path which is inside WEB-INF folder. That can not be accessed from outside. But in my old application this link appears as below.

```
http://server:port/myAppName/myJspName.jsp?d-445967-e=3&6578706f7274=1
```

Since this was an Struts application so folder struct was little different where we had JSPs outside

WEB-INF folder.

Same issue I am facing with pagination links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your view part like jsp outside the web-inf folder. because we cant access web-inf resources.

Comment: so create a spring controller and the spring controller access the view part in web-inf

Comment: I think, I did not get you. Could you please explain little more!!

Comment: i means every request that are handle your web/application sever is controller request like (home.so) etc not create a link that are ended by .jsp extension.when controller handle the request and implement the business logic then response comes to view part.

Comment: I think, we dont need to call any controller on click of these links, its Display Tag's default feature. Otherwise  I'll have to handle each click and generate the rqeuested file/content. What I am looking here, Is there any way I can edit the link before they are assigned to these Export Options.

Comment: @vikash please consider editing your answer to include the additional detail you provided in the comments.